# how to compile ffmpeg ARM64 executable binary with android_camera enabled

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, compile, camera, binary-files

I am having some trouble because, most of the post I read for compiling ffmpeg for android actually are only generating the shared library (.so) files which can then be linked into an android project via the NDK and JNI interface.

However, I am more wanting to instead just compile a ARM64 executable binary of FFMPEG 4.1 with the android camera device supported. Does anyone have experience with this?